# Can ubuntu touch scopes access the dbus at any time?

Tags: application-development

I was thinking of writing a scope for downloading music and video content from its sources, and since there is not yet a UI for the ubuntu download manager daemon, it seems like there is "no" downloader. Even when you try to download something from the browser, there is no app to actually take over from the browser and effect the download.

Is it possible for one to connect to the Ubuntu DownloadManager daemon using dbus and implement downloads, including information from the daemon about current downloads?